# Кнопки "войти через"

Tags: haml

Где взять или, как сделать такие кнопки, как тут http://askbook.me/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У всем этих соц. сетей есть соответствующие API, которые позволяют использовтать учетную запись для входа на сторонние ресурсы. Кроме того, можно воспользоваться, например, сервисом [uLogin](http://ulogin.ru/)

Comment: мне просто надо, что-бы мои картинки были. Почти, как на этом сайте

Comment: Брысь отсюда. Здесь для программистов.

Comment: @Zow, я уже старенький и немного туплю, поэтому не очень понимаю связь между: "**сделать такие кнопки**" и "**надо, что-бы мои картинки были**". Вот если бы у вас получилось как-то более осмысленно растолковать, то возможно, что и решение нашлось бы.

Comment: то есть или такие, как на этом сайте или же сервис по типу uLogin, но только, что бы я мог сделать там свои картинки, то на uLogine они уродские

Comment: @Deonis, а что будет, если все пенсионеры вдруг прекратят обращать внимание на малолетних идиотов? Я об этом только что думал :)

Comment: @Zow, это же ближе к делу. [Замена иконок социальных сервисов.][1]

   [1]:http://ulogin.ru/custom_buttons.html

Comment: @klopp, тогда у "малолетних идиотов" не будет ни единого шанса на то, чтоб приростить хотя бы одну извилину к единственно существующей и человечество вымрет не дождавшись второго пришествия ;)

Comment: @Deonis, твои опасения сильно преувеличены, чесслово :) Просто здесь (ну, как мне кажется) пасутся ленивые бездари, их не жалко. А делом занимаются другие, их публично не видать, и идиотских вопросов по курсовым и дипломам они тут не задают. Поэтому я без жалости отстреливаю здесь - "профильных" студентов. И с радостью принимаю вопросы от людей, которым действительно хочется разобраться.